# Move a control to a splitcontainer runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, user-controls, controls

I have a custom control (a textbox) that is slow to replicate. I have have code that adds a new split container to the current form when the user clicks the button. Is there any way that I can move my existing control to the sub panels in the split container at **run-time** or would I have to make a new instance in the panel? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the `TextBox` to your `SplitContainer` like this:

Assuming the TextBox name is `txt1`, SplitContainer's name is `spl1` and `spl1` has a panel called `panel1`

```
spl1.Panel1.Controls.Add(txt1);
txt1.Location=new Point(10,10);
```

Comment: To the one who downvoted my answer. Can you explain WHY? :|